# How do I automatically assign the latest location tax to a product?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have 3 models; Product, Tax and Location. Whenever a product gets created I want to assign the latest tax of the location if it has a tax.

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :products
  has_many :taxes
end

class Tax < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date # I use this to get the latest tax
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :tax_id
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :tax
end
```

Now I tried this in my `Product` model:

```
after_create :assign_latest_location_tax

private

def assign_latest_location_tax
  if self.location.tax.present?
    self.tax_id = self.location.tax.order("date DESC").first.id
  end
end
```

But this gives me the error:

```
NoMethodError in ProductsController#create

undefined method `tax' for #<Location:0x4669bf0>
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Location :has_many tasks => you should use self.location.taxes.last instead of self.location.tax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location has_many taxes, therefore the method it exposes to access it's taxes is `taxes`, not `tax`.

The following should work:

```
self.tax_id = self.location.taxes.order("date DESC").first.id
```

And if you use the `after_create` callback you must call save again on the end of it. To avoid this, you may use the `before_create` callback.

Comment: This works but it doesn't (if that makes sense) as the ID of Tax isn't getting assigned.

Comment: If you are setting it on the after_create method you need to call save again, or update_column. You can also put the code to set this variable on the before_create, the location will also be available there.

Answer (score 1):

This code should work:

```
def assign_latest_location_tax
  if self.location.taxes.count > 0
    self.tax_id = self.location.taxes.order("date DESC").first.id
  end
end
```